# How to give parameters inside function expression in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
function callFunction(fun) {
  fun();
}


var calculation = function(a, b){
  var multiplication = a * b;
  var addition = a + b;
  var subtraction = a - b;
  console.log("Addition: " + addition);
  console.log("Subtraction: " + subtraction);
  console.log("Multiplication: " + multiplication);
}


callFunction(calculation(9,3));
```

How to give the parameters inside function expression? why not `callFunction(calculation(9,3));` line does not work.

Comment: callFunction expects a function to be its argument , and you are padding return value of calculation(9,3) to it

Comment: Make the variables constant, it’s better that way
it gives you a clean code and better performance also fewer bugs. Sometimes the initialization of a variable won’t be just a simple assignment. Several lines (or more) might be used to give a proper value. In that case making the variable const will force you to move such initialization to a separate place.

Comment: And the return value of `calculation` is `undefined` as it doesn't return anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
callFunction(()=>calculation(9,3));
```

or es-5 compatible

```js
callFunction(function(){
  return calculation(9,3)
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please explain `callFunction( ***()=>*** calculation(9,3));` . The starred part of the code. What it does or what is the meaning of those symbols?

Comment: @AkashJaladurgam it's [fat arrow syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) function declaration; and is almost the same thing as normal function declaration.  basically we define a function that will return a function; and when you pass it as argumaent; the return value will be excuted as you expect it

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you are *calling* the funciton.

You can use:

```
callFunction(calculation.bind(null, 9, 3));
```

or

```
callFunction(function () { return calculation(9, 3); });
```

Answer (score 0):

calculation(9,3) is executed and then its result which is `undefined` is passed to callFunction.

Try this -

```
function callFunction(fun, a, b) {
  fun(a, b);
}

var calculation = function(a, b){
  var multiplication = a * b;
  var addition = a + b;
  var subtraction = a - b;
  console.log("Addition: " + addition);
  console.log("Subtraction: " + subtraction);
  console.log("Multiplication: " + multiplication);
}

callFunction(calculation, 9, 3);
```